# How to access JTextField contents in another class

Tags: java, swing

The Jtextfield which is initilaized in login class needs to be accessed in Clayout 
when Login button is clicked. I want to compare the data of the JTextfield with some string and perform some operation.
But it is throughing an exception

`"TextField undefined"` can anyone help me plzzz

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CLayout {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayout demo");
    JPanel panelCont = new JPanel();
    JPanel log = new LoginView();
    JPanel Img = new ImageGallery();
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

    public CLayout() {
        final String user = CLayout.getFieldText();
        panelCont.setLayout(cl);
        log.setLayout(new BoxLayout(log, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        Img.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Img, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        JButton loginButton = new JButton("login");
        JButton registerButton = new JButton("register");
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField(20);
        loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        log.add(loginButton);
        registerButton.setBounds(180, 80, 80, 25);
        log.add(registerButton);
        panelCont.add(log, "1");
        panelCont.add(Img, "2");
        cl.show(panelCont, "1");
        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (user == "imagegallery") {
                    cl.show(panelCont, "2");
                }
            }
        });
        registerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                cl.show(panelCont, "1");
            }
        });
        frame.add(panelCont);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setTitle("     Image Gallery    ");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}

class ImageGallery extends JPanel {

    private ImageIcon myImage1 = new ImageIcon("Chrysanthemum.jpg");
    private ImageIcon myImage2 = new ImageIcon("Desert.jpg");
    private ImageIcon myImage3 = new ImageIcon("Jellyfish.jpg");
    private ImageIcon myImage4 = new ImageIcon("principal.jpg");
    private ImageIcon myImage5 = new ImageIcon("student.jpg");
    private ImageIcon myImage6 = new ImageIcon("library.jpg");
    private ImageIcon myImage7 = new ImageIcon("sports.jpg");
    private ImageIcon myImage8 = new ImageIcon("class.jpg");
    JPanel ImageGallery = new JPanel();
    private ImageIcon[] myImages = new ImageIcon[8];
    private int curImageIndex = 0;

    public ImageGallery() {
        ImageGallery.add(new JLabel(myImage1));
        myImages[0] = myImage1;
        myImages[1] = myImage2;
        myImages[2] = myImage3;
        myImages[3] = myImage4;
        myImages[4] = myImage5;
        myImages[5] = myImage6;
        myImages[6] = myImage7;
        myImages[7] = myImage8;
        add(ImageGallery, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton PREVIOUS = new JButton("Previous");
        JButton FILE = new JButton("File");
        JButton EDIT = new JButton("Edit");
        JButton NEXT = new JButton("Next");
        JButton HELP = new JButton("Help");
        JPanel Menu = new JPanel();
        Menu.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 5));
        Menu.add(FILE);
        Menu.add(EDIT);
        Menu.add(PREVIOUS);
        Menu.add(NEXT);
        Menu.add(HELP);
        add(Menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //register listener
        PreviousButtonListener PreviousButton = new PreviousButtonListener();
        NextButtonListener NextButton = new NextButtonListener();
        //add listeners to corresponding componenets 
        PREVIOUS.addActionListener(PreviousButton);
        NEXT.addActionListener(NextButton);
    }

    class PreviousButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (curImageIndex > 0 && curImageIndex <= 5) {
                ImageGallery.remove(0);
                curImageIndex = curImageIndex - 1;
                ImageIcon TheImage = myImages[curImageIndex];
                ImageGallery.add(new JLabel(TheImage));
                ImageGallery.validate();
                ImageGallery.repaint();
            } else {
                ImageGallery.remove(0);
                ImageGallery.add(new JLabel(myImage6));
                curImageIndex = 5;
                ImageGallery.validate();
                ImageGallery.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    class NextButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (curImageIndex >= 0 && curImageIndex < 5) {
                ImageGallery.remove(0);
                curImageIndex = curImageIndex + 1;
                ImageIcon TheImage = myImages[curImageIndex];
                ImageGallery.add(new JLabel(TheImage));
                ImageGallery.validate();
                ImageGallery.repaint();
            } else {
                ImageGallery.remove(0);
                ImageGallery.add(new JLabel(myImage1));
                curImageIndex = 0;
                ImageGallery.validate();
                ImageGallery.repaint();
            }

        }
    }
}

class LoginView extends JPanel {

    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
    JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);

    public LoginView() {
        userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
        add(userLabel);
        userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
        add(userText);
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
        add(passwordLabel);
        passwordText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
        add(passwordText);
    }

    String getFieldText()
       return userText.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: This `user == "imagegallery"` is not how to compare `String`s in Java, use `String#equals` or `String#equalsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 2):

You could write a getter for it:

```
public String getTextFromTextField(){
  return jTextField1.getText();
}
```

and simply call that.

Comment: answers here should be longer, meaning 2-3 short sentences and code (if needed :-), otherwise very short answers can be target for id***s(community) here and closed as non_answer by community here

Comment: I'll keep it in mind. but basically, that is a valid (and complete) answer imo. I might just as well be wrong, but the other direct way to do it, is making the jTextField public and get it's text like that, which I would not recommend at all.

Comment: You should avoid exposing UI elements unnecessarily, as it exposes them to abuse by the caller...

Comment: Which is why I left that possiblity out of my answer. I agree that making the field public is bad design.

Comment: So is returning via a getter

Comment: so, how would you implement it? if he needs the text, either you get the text through a getter, or (which is even more ridiculous) you call a method that calls a setter within the calling class.
if on the other hand you were talking about returning the JTextField through the getter, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Change your work flow.  Instead of having the `Register` and `Login` buttons in your `CLayout`, they should be part of the `LoginView` component.

When either of these are clicked, you need to raise some kind of notification that registered listeners can pick up and take action on.

You would then need to provide some simple getters to provide a means for interested parties to obtain the information that they wanted from the `LoginView`

For example, you could provide a `addActionListener` method which simply attached the listener to the `Login` and `Register` buttons, for example...

```
public class LoginView extends JPanel {

    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
    JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
    private final JButton loginButton;
    private final JButton registerButton;

    public static final String LOGIN = "Login";
    public static final String REGISTER = "Regster";

    public LoginView() {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

        add(userLabel);
        add(userText);
        add(passwordLabel);
        add(passwordText);

        loginButton = new JButton("login");
        loginButton.setActionCommand(LOGIN);
        registerButton = new JButton("register");
        registerButton.setActionCommand(REGISTER);

    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        loginButton.addActionListener(listener);
        registerButton.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userText.getText();
    }

    public char[] getPassword() {
        return passwordText.getPassword();
    }

}
```

Then in your `CLayout` class, you would simply need to create a `ActionListener`, register it to your `LoginView` class and wait for the user to press either of the buttons.  When `actionPerformed` is called, you would simply use the getters to obtain the information you want and use it as you need, based on the type of action triggered, for example...

```
public class CLayout {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayout demo");
    JPanel panelCont = new JPanel();
    LoginView log = new LoginView();
    JPanel Img = new ImageGallery();

    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

    public CLayout() {
        panelCont.setLayout(cl);
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField(20);
        panelCont.add(log, "1");
        panelCont.add(Img, "2");
        cl.show(panelCont, "1");

        ActionListener loginListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String userName = log.getUserName();
                char[] password = log.getPassword();
                if (LoginView.LOGIN.equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                    //...
                } else if (LoginView.REGISTER.equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                    //...
                }
            }
        };

        log.addActionListener(loginListener);

        frame.add(panelCont);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setTitle("     Image Gallery    ");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CLayout();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is just an example, personally, I would set up my own listener, which provided `register` and `login` methods that would be called based on what the user choose to do, passing the information you need in order to take further action...

Also, avoid using `setBounds`, your components are under the control of layout managers and these calls will either be ignored or will cause issues and conflicts with the layout managers

Answer (score 0):

In the Login class make the JTextField public (I wouldn't recommend this), or add a getter. Here's an example of a getter, in case you don't know what one is:

```
private int cats = 5;

public int getCats() 
{
    return cats;
}
```

Comment: indeed, making the JTextField public is a possibility as well, but risky, since you don't just make it possible to 'get' the contents, also to manipulate the field. I would recommend the getter.

Comment: i made login class public and  loginButton.addActionListener(new              ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                    
                                 String user=userText.getText().toString(); 
                                  
                                if(user.equals("imagegallery"))
    cl.show(panelCont, "2");
                                
                                
    }
   });

Comment: but it is still showing me error "cannot find symbol userText"

Comment: First off, it's not making the Login class public that's in issue. You need to make the JTextField public. I'd recommend you start with something smaller so you can get a better understanding of access modifiers.